# Remove Specific Buttons from WP Editor TinyMCE

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am trying to figure out how to remove specific buttons from the TinyMCE editor. I have researched the arguments in the codex but for TinyMCE is just says array and not sure if I can include some paramters in my arguments of which buttons to show/hide?

I am using the editor in a gravity form and my code is as follows so far

```
add_action( 'gform_field_input', 'gforms_wp_editor', 10, 5 );

function gforms_wp_editor( $input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id ) {
if( $field["cssClass"] == 'richtext' ) {
ob_start();
wp_editor( $value, "input_{$form_id}_{$field['id']}",
array(
'media_buttons' => false,
'quicktags' => false,

'textarea_name' => "input_{$field['id']}"
)   );
$input = ob_get_clean();
}
return $input;
}
```

I have removed the HTML tab using the `quicktags` to false, so hoping I can do something similar to strip out buttons from the editor.

buttons shown right now with the code above are as follows

[image]

**Note:** 'teeny' editor is now what I need, just in case someone suggests

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tinymce` parameter allows you to pass configuration options directly to TinyMCE - see the docs for [theme_advanced_buttons](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_advanced_buttons_1_n) and [theme_advanced_disable](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_advanced_disable), and the [button reference](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Buttons/controls).

To show only the bold, italic and underline buttons:

```
wp_editor($value, "input...", array(
    'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,underline',
        'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons3' => ''
    )
));
```

Or, to show everything *except* the bold, italic and underline buttons:

```
wp_editor($value, "input...", array(
    'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_disable' => 'bold,italic,underline'
    )
));
```

As requested, your code modified:

```
add_action( 'gform_field_input', 'gforms_wp_editor', 10, 5 );

function gforms_wp_editor( $input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id ) {
    if( $field["cssClass"] == 'richtext' ) {
        ob_start();
        wp_editor( $value, "input_{$form_id}_{$field['id']}",
            array(
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'quicktags'     => false,
                'textarea_name' => "input_{$field['id']}",
                'tinymce'       => array(
                    'theme_advanced_disable' => 'bold,italic,underline'
                )
            )
        );
        $input = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the code, looks like it will work but when I implement it into my code above it breaks the page. Could you post your code updates into my code above as a full piece I can copy. Not sure if I am implementing your part wrongly into my code

Comment: I am probably just not closing an array in the right spot or something :(

Comment: When I'm working with Wordpress code, I usually copy it into an editor with syntax highlighting and then copy it back when I'm finished, for exactly that reason - something as simple as a stray closing brace can be a nightmare to track down :)