# How to hide buttons in TinyMCE 4.0 - WordPress 3.9

Tags: wordpress, tinymce-4

In last version of TinyMCE there was simply code to hide buttons in visual editor ([Remove Specific Buttons from WP Editor TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293348/remove-specific-buttons-from-wp-editor-tinymce)). But with WordPress 3.9 TinyMCE 4.0 have other API.

Someone know how to do it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function delete_button($buttons) {  
   unset($buttons[6]);
   unset($buttons[7]);
   unset($buttons[8]);
   unset($buttons[9]);
   unset($buttons[12]);
   unset($buttons[14]);
   return $buttons;
}

add_filter('mce_buttons', 'delete_button');
```

print_r($buttons) to read specific buttons numbers.

Comment: What if other filters add/remove buttons before you? Adding the `n`th button is probably not what you want, did you try the examples here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_buttons,_mce_buttons_2,_mce_buttons_3,_mce_buttons_4

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you can use something like this to remove the default buttons from the WP tinyMCE.

```
// Remove TinyMCE Default Button

function myplugin_tinymce_buttons( $buttons ) {
      //Remove the text color selector
      $remove = 'blockquote'; //default blockquote button

      //Find the array key and then unset
      if ( ( $key = array_search( $remove, $buttons ) ) !== false )
        unset( $buttons[$key] );

      return $buttons;
 }
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'myplugin_tinymce_buttons' );
```

to know what is the name of the element you need to use your browser dev tools. Simply highlight the element and see the class. It will be also the name. For example:
[where to see the name of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJS8C.png)