# Disabling some buttons from wp_editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I use tinyMce editor in meta boxes of Wordpress by the following line of code, I want to remove some buttons when I use there. I don't want to affect the main editor. I know how to remove some buttons, which is [told here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103347/removing-buttons-from-the-editor).

My question is, is it possible to disable some buttons (e.g. more) when I call editor with wp_editor. I checked its [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor), arguments doesn't seem to support this.

```
wp_editor( $careers_settings["description"], "editor", array("media_buttons"=>FALSE,  "textarea_name"=>"description", "textarea_rows"=>5) );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the referenced manual again - it's possible to have tinymce as parameter and pass an array of configuration options, e.g. like

```
wp_editor($value, "input...", array(
    'tinymce' => array( .. //tinymce configuration options here )
     ))
```

Haven't tried it out, but it should work like that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I try to figure out how it's possible to set buttons with that configuration. I tried "toolbar" key to set default buttons but didn't work as in Javascript side.

Comment: You set "toolbar" as param for wp_editor or as option for the tinymce-param inside the wp_editor-options?

Comment: Just found this as reference, maybe you should check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293348/remove-specific-buttons-from-wp-editor-tinymce

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's a bit late to answer but in case it might be useful for someone. Since Tinymce 4, "toolbar1" must be used and "teeny" must be set as false to modify buttons :

```
wp_editor(
'id',
'value',
array(
  'teeny'=>false,
  'media_buttons'=>false,
  'tinymce' => array(
    'toolbar1' => 'bold, italic, underline,|,fontsizeselect',
    'toolbar2'=>false
  ),
)
);
```

Also I added "toolbar2" to the array. I realized that although I only set toolbar1, additional buttons still appear in some cases. Setting toolbar2 as false will remove default buttons on the second buttons row.