# Is it possible to remove or configure menubar from tinymce editor in a WORDPRESS plugin admin page?

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I have scoured WordPress, and TinyMCE documentation and stackoverflow and wordpress.stackexchange for an answer to this problem. Right now, I can see **NO duplicates** to this question.

**I want to remove the menubar from a tinymce editor in a WordPress plugin admin page.**

I am building a WordPress plugin. As part of the plugin's functionality a user has to add content using TinyMCE. I use `wp_editor()` which adds a TinyMCE instance to the plugin's admin page.

TinyMCE works fine. I have been able to configure buttons using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872094/2298108 . However, this does not help remove or configure the menubar. I have tried adding `menubar=>false` to the `tinymce` array.

I've even looked for a frontend hack to access the editor and remove the menubar. Because WordPress instantiates tinymce, I have NO access to `tinymce.init()`. I have tried using the frontend event `addeditor` which fires, and gives "access" to the editor, but there doesn't seem to be any method to remove the menubar.

My php inline code:

```
$settings= ['menubar'=> false,'toolbar1' => 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,hr,|bullist,numlist','toolbar2'=>false];

wp_editor($this->form_confirmation,'xxx_form_confirmation_mce',['editor_height'=>200,'media_buttons'=>false,'quicktags'=>false,'menubar' =>false,'tinymce' => $settings]);
```

`$this->form_confirmation` is a string and gets added to the content screen of the editor.

*NOTE: I am using the "TinyMCE Advanced" WordPress plugin.*

Comment: How are you adding your TinyMCE editor to your page? I tried the first example from the [wp_editor() documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) and I don't see the menu bar.

Comment: @cabrerahector I have added my code.

Comment: I didn't mention I am using the tinyMCE advanced plugin too. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: This is what I get with the stock TinyMCE editor & your code: https://prnt.sc/in5zi8 (no menu bar). With TinyMCE Advanced it does display the menu bar even when you tell it not to (probably a bug in the plugin? You should let its developer know). I found a workaround, I'll post my answer in a bit.

Comment: thx @cabrerahector the accepted answer works perfectly. I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook into `tiny_mce_before_init` to further customize the TinyMCE editor before it gets loaded.

This removed the menu bar for me:

```
function wp2641_disable_tinymce_menu_bar( $in ) {
    $in['menubar'] = false;
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wp2641_disable_tinymce_menu_bar' );
```